# Display labels left upper from text field

Tags: css, html, label

I want my labels display left up in the text-fields, here is the screenshot where i want them exactly  http://s20.postimg.org/p8h11xrot/label_1.png.
I don't know really how to do that i tried with `text-align` or `float: left`.

this is my css file:

```
body {

}

#container{
    background-color:#ccccff;
    width:100%;
    margin-left:auto;
    margin-right:auto;

}
.content {
    padding: 5px;
    width:100%;
    margin-left:auto;
    margin-right:auto;
    text-align:center;
}
label {
  text-align: center;

}
article p{
    text-align:center;    
}
header{
    width: auto;
    height: 100px;
    background-color: #ffffff;
    background: url(image.png) center center no-repeat;
    text-align:center;
}
footer{
    text-align:center;
    background-color: #999999;
}
```

Index.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Intes - Register</title>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/main.css">
    </head>
    <body>
        <header> Header Image </header>
        <section id="container">
            <article><p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur 
                adipiscing elit. Sed eget vehicula sapien.
                Donec vitae quam id dolor pretium viverra. 
                Nulla viverra quam eget fringilla ultrices.</article>

            <label>First Name</label>
            <br />
            <div class="content">
            <input type="text" name="first_name" size="50">
            <br />
            </div>
            <label>Last Name</label>
            <br />
            <div class="content">
            <input type="text" name="last_name" size="50">
            <br />
            </div>
            <label>E-mail Address</label>
            <br />
            <div class="content">
            <input type="text" name="email_address" size="50">
            <br />
            </div>
            <div class="content">
            <input type="submit" value="Register">
            </div>
        </section>
        <footer>copyright stuff</footer>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Did you try using `text-align:left` ?

Comment: yes i tried, but they appear on the left side of the page , not on top of the text field

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To have your desired visual effect you need to figure out to center the form and
get the labels to show above the inputs.

```
#container{
  text-align: center;
}

/* FORMS */
#my_form {
  display: inline-block;
  text-align: left;
  line-height: 1.5;
}
 #my_form  label {
  display: block;
}
#my_form input {
    margin: 0.25em 0 0.5em;
}
```

http://fiddle.jshell.net/g4yzZ/13/
http://fiddle.jshell.net/g4yzZ/13/show

Comment: thnx a lot it helped me much, and how do I display now the button on the right.

Comment: #my_form  input[type="submit"] {
    float: right;
} - http://fiddle.jshell.net/3TFQE/2/show/

Comment: THnx i already did it, but you helped me much, thnx thnx thnx :)

Answer (score 0):

Float your .labels and input elements to the left {float:left} and use {clear:right} on the labels.

Answer (score 0):

Give the label or container a width, and then use text-align: left. It should work.

```
label {
    width: 100px;
    text-align: center;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can accomplish this with `width`.

The trick is to wrap the `input` and `label` tags in wrapper divs. You almost got there, but the nesting in your code was off.

Once that's done, you can set the `content` class to the width of your inputs, `333px` and align it center with margin, then `text-align` left the labels, which are now flush with the inputs.

The working code is here: http://jsfiddle.net/bronzehedwick/xpB3v/

And the relevant css:

```
.content {
  padding: 5px;
  width:333px;
  margin: 0 auto;
}
label {
  text-align: left;
  display: block;
}
```